# How can I install a nest thermostat with no wires?

Tags: heating, installation, thermostat

I have zoned heating/AC/heat pump.  My original thermostat on the wall is NOT connected to any wires, in other words it is wireless.  I thought it had wires so bought the new Nest thermostat.  Unfortunately when taking the original thermostat off the wall discovered it has no wires connected to furnace.  Is there any way I can still hook up the Nest thermostat since there are no wires from the furnace to the original thermostat?

Answer (score 7):

You would need to hook up the nest thermostat where the wires are. This might be right next to your furnace. The nest might not work the best there. You can also buy some thermostat wire and pull it through the walls to a better location as well.